# Java Regex - whitespace & matching words

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm new to Regex but I think my problem should be solved using it.  Basically, I want to replace whitespace in a string with "dog", as long as the words "cat" or "bird" or "dog" aren't before or after.

Example:

```
    Good Dog = Good Dog
    Large Brown = Large Dog Brown
    Cat Ugly = Cat Ugly
```

So only the second string would be modified.  I can handle something like this easily string replace etc, but i'm curious to know if this should be done in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms. Your code can look more or less like

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("(?<!cat|bird|dog)\\s(?!cat|bird|dog)"," dog ")
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                               negative look-behind   negative look-ahead
```

You can improve this regex by making it case insensitive with `(?i)` flag.
You can also add [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to make sure you are matching whole words, and not only its parts like `cataclysm`.

Demo (I also used [non-capturing group `(?:...)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to increase performance a little):

```
String[] data ={ "Good Dog", "Large Brown", "Cat Ugly"};
for (String s : data){
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!\\b(?:cat|bird|dog)\\b)\\s(?!\\b(?:cat|bird|dog)\\b)"," dog "));
}
```

Output:

```
Good Dog
Large dog Brown
Cat Ugly
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am in the middle of improving this answer :) was looking for correct links which could provide more informations to readers.